# Smooth animation of marker over given array of coordinates

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have an array of coordinates on which I have to perform marker animation  Smoothly without any pause.

I have also tried [Animated marker position](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#animated-marker-position)  but no smoothness.

How can I achieve it?

I want this scenario
[image: 1]

Comment: Did you find any solution ?